# How can I configure the host of my remote server?

Tags: git, ssh

I try to see all my remote banches with:

```
git fetch --all
```

I get the error message:

```
The authenticity of host 'meinserver.de (111.222.3.444)' can't be established.
```

But `'meinserver.de'` is not the correct name of my host. It is actually `'mylovelyhost.de'` where can I change the host settings?

This is my `.ssh/config` file:

```
UserKnownHostsFile coding/.ssh/known_hosts
```

`# lovely`

```
Host mylovelyhost
User mylovelyuser
HostName mylovelyhost.de
Port 22
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed12345
```

Comment: This isn't really a Git issue, it's an ssh issue. Ssh is looking for the host fingerprint in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file and not finding it. Why it is calling the host `meinserver.de` here I don't know off-hand, but see also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/285520/162084) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/683802/162084). They link to [this](https://serverfault.com/q/193631/549786) which in turn links to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/895661/549786).

Comment: @torek I added the HostKeyAlias to my config file like you recommended. But still I get the error message `The authenticity of host '[mylovelyhost.de]:22 ([999.111.222.33]:22)' can't be established.`

Comment: You'll need to get the *fingerprint* from the host and put it into your `known_hosts` file. That's what `ssh-keyscan` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt this command :

```
git remote set-url <name-of-the-remote> <mylovelyhost.de[...].git>
```

Comment: You mean like this?  `git remote set-url origin ssh://mylovelyhost.de/html/myproject.git`?

Comment: or `git remote set-url origin ssh://mylovelyuser@mylovelyhost.de:/html/myproject.git` what is the correct way?

Comment: I tried the second one

Comment: Now when I do `git fetch --all` I get: `The authenticity of host '[mylovelyhost.de]:22 ([999.111.222.33]:2222)' can't be established.Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (coding/.ssh/known_hosts).`

Comment: I can't know the exact syntax you'd need , but the second one seems good.

If you can't ssh to the machine, that's not really a git problem though, so you'll have to debug that independently !